# Elasticsearch: Tire to Elasticsearch Persistence migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I would like to migrate from Tire (retire) gem to Elasticsearch Persistence gem, in Tire I used to set the index settings from inside the model as shown below

```
settings :number_of_shards => 5,
        :number_of_replicas => 1,
        :analysis => {
          :analyzer => {
            :my_pattern => {
               "type"         => "custom",
                "tokenizer" => "keyword",
                 "filter"    =>  ["url_ngram", "lowercase"]
               }
          }, :filter => {
       :url_stop => {
         :type => "stop",
         :stopwords => ["="]
       },
       :url_ngram => {
         :type => "nGram",
         :min_gram => 4,
         :max_gram => 40
       }
       }

        } do
 mapping {

   indexes :msgpriority, :type => 'string',      :analyzer => 'snowball'
   indexes :msghostname, :type => 'string',        :analyzer => 'snowball'
   indexes :msgtext, :type => 'string',        :analyzer => 'my_pattern'
   indexes :msgdatetime,  :type => 'date',       :include_in_all => false
 }
end
```

Now I'm using the Repository object and I want to apply the same settings (mainly analyzer)

The code below doesn't work, even when I change the number of shards as if I wrote nothing

```
REPOSITORY = Elasticsearch::Persistence::Repository.new do
# Configure the Elasticsearch client
client Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'], log: true
now_time = Time.now
# Set a custom index name
index "ip_logstreams_#{now_time.year}_#{now_time.month}_#{now_time.day}"

# Set a custom document type
type  :log_entry

# Specify the class to inicialize when deserializing documents
klass LogEntry

# Configure the settings and mappings for the Elasticsearch index
settings number_of_shards: 2, :analysis => {
 :analyzer => {
   :my_pattern => {
    "type"         => "custom",
    "tokenizer" => "keyword",
    "filter"    =>  ["url_ngram", "lowercase"]
  }
  }, :filter => {
    :url_stop => {
      :type => "stop",
      :stopwords => ["="]
      },
    :url_ngram => {
      :type => "nGram",
      :min_gram => 4,
      :max_gram => 40
    }
  }

  } do
    mapping {

      indexes :msgpriority, :type => 'string',      :analyzer => 'snowball'
      indexes :msghostname, :type => 'string',        :analyzer => 'snowball'
      indexes :msgtext, :type => 'string',        :analyzer => 'my_pattern'
      indexes :msgdatetime,  :type => 'date',       :include_in_all => false
    }
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

When I issue

```
REPOSITORY.create_index! force: true
```

changes are applied, but I think the settings in elasticsearch are messed up as shown in screenshot (grabbed from head plugin)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using [elasticsearch/elasticsearch-model](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) - it provides [automatic callbacks](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model#automatic-callbacks) that suppose to help you persist data around.

Comment: I'm currently keeping my model with Tire using "include Tire::Model::Persistence", I'm still using Tire because it has the option to search in multiple indices unlike the new gem

Comment: Well Tire is obsolete and as its new name suggests also retired. So in long term you should switch to 'official' ElasticSearch gem or use something like strecher. Strecher on the other hand already supports multi search. Other option is to just make search query to multiple indexes by 'hand'... 

$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index_a,index_b/tweet/_search?q=tag:wow'

Comment: Agree but that doesn't solve the initial problem, I've updated the question, should the settings look that way or should they be presented in a JSON structure?

Comment: This is how [mapping/settings usually look](https://gist.github.com/otobrglez/e2ba9cf1e61febd17546). I use concern to keep my code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

When using the repository object in elasticsearch gem we should issue

```
REPOSITORY.create_index!
```

this will create the index with supplied settings, you can add the `force: true` if you want to re-create the index again